# fulltext_stoplists to database_principals issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, dbcc, system-tables

When I run a DBCC check against the database, it informs me that there is an issue with the `sys.fulltext_stoplists` object.  It appears that the `principal_id` in stoplists does not have a relationship with `database_principals`:

[image: Query result]

What would be the best way to address the issue? It is difficult to modify data in system tables.

Answer (score 2):

The [sys.fulltext_stoplists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-fulltext-stoplists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) doc says the column `principal_id` is the *ID of the database principal that owns the stoplist.* You can specify it as one of the [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-stoplist-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#arguments) of the `CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST` command:

> AUTHORIZATION *owner_name* 
> Specifies the name of a database principal to
> own of the stoplist. owner_name must either be the name of a principal
> of which the current user is a member, or the current user must have
> IMPERSONATE permission on owner_name. If not specified, ownership is
> given to the current user.

It appears the owner of the object no longer exists. You can assign a new owner using the [ALTER AUTHORIZATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) like this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON FULLTEXT STOPLIST::CustomStopword TO SomeExistingUser;
```

After that, run the DBCC check again to see if everything is ok.

Comment: Hi Ronaldo.  I now receive the following message: Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: Hello, @CalgaryCoolCat. "A severe error occurred on the current command." what command?

Comment: ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON FULLTEXT STOPLIST::CustomStopword TO maintenance;  @ronaldo

Comment: Ok, @CalgaryCoolCat . **1** - When you marked the correct answer did it work (but now it doesn't) or you marked it before running the command? **2** - What does this command `SELECT type_desc FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'maintenance';` return? **3** - Does `DBCC CHECKDB;` return any error? (You might wanna run this last one in your maintenance window)

Comment: @CalgaryCoolCat, if you were able to find a solution to the problem, please, post what you have done as an answer to the question so that others might benefit from the knowledge ;)